# Media Center on Vista restarting randomly

Tags: windows-vista, reboot

Guys, just built this machine to be used as DVR with Vista Home Premium on it. All new components, this includes the 270W HTPC PSU (http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817339023). Patched it and loaded latest driver for all hardware. Machine was running fine on idle for couple of days, but when i start to setup the MCE it randomly reboots, seems like when it does "a little work". Nothing in the Event Viewer besides the "unexpected shutdown", no blue screen. I turned off the "automatic restart" to get more info but it just restarts itself anyways. I am thinking it could be the PSU since there is nothing in the EV. What do you think, any suggestions are welcomed :)

Wojo

Answer (score 0):

I suspect hardware.  I'd do each of these in order:

- If you are overclocking, stop overclocking.  Forever.  Trust me.
- Burn a CD with memtest86 on it, and run it overnight.  It is a memory torture test which will stress the memory path from the CPU.  If it also locks up or crashes, you have bad hardware -- either CPU, motherboard, or RAM.
- Remove and re-seat all cards and memory.  Test.  If it fixes it, something just came loose or had a bit of problems with a clean contact.  Sometimes this happens when you move a machine or with temperature changes.  PeeCee hardware isn't all that robust.
- If you can, remove half the RAM.  If it still craps out, try the other half.  If it still craps out, chances are your RAM isn't the problem.
- Remove hardware (internal cards, USB devices) and see if it stays up.  If it does, for longer than is now usual, put them back in.  Start with the cards first, and see if it continues to work well.
- If you get all the way here, and it's not just Windows being Windows, it's likely time to replace the CPU, motherboard, or RAM.

Comment: +1 for "stop overclocking forever".  The rest is all good advice too.